# How to access master page control in child .aspx page (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my masterpage.cs i am assigning a value to a hidden field (`hfSession="abc";`)

In my content page (default.aspx) i need to access this value in my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function(sender, e) 
    {   
        var Sessioninfo= $get('<%= ((Hiddenfield)this.Master.FindControl("ct100_hfSession")).ClientID %>');
</script>
```

but here i get an error :

> object reference not set to an  instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

I use this little javascript util function:

```
// This function returns a control's (mangled) client id given its ASP.NET Id
function GetClientId(strid) {
var count = document.forms[0].length;
var i = 0;
var eleName;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    eleName = document.forms[0].elements[i].id;
    pos = eleName.indexOf(strid);
    if (pos >= 0) break;
}
return '#' + eleName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
Sessioninfo= $get('<%= ((Hiddenfield)this.Master.FindControl("hfSession")).ClientID %>');
```